# Serial number generator in R

Tags: r

I would like to generate serial number using R.My Serial number depends on certain variables,let say `a`,`b`,`c` & `d`.When any of these values changed then serial number will be refreshed from 1 again.
For example

```
a b c d e  sl
1 1 1 1 31  1 
1 1 1 1 32  2
1 1 1 1 33  3
2 1 1 1 34  1
```

Here my `sl` is linked with e but get refreshed when a changed to 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `paste` the dependent columns together. Find the `length` of equal values in the vector and use `sequence` to generate the required output. This would reset if any value in any of the `cols` changes.

```
cols <- c('a','b','c','d')
df$sl <- sequence(rle(with(df[cols], paste0(a,b,c,d)))$lengths)
df

#  a b c d  e sl
#1 1 1 1 1 31  1
#2 1 1 1 1 32  2
#3 1 1 1 1 33  3
#4 2 1 1 1 34  1
```